# Ionic Cordova SQLite, insert data if not exists, if data exists replace the old data

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am developing an application with Ionic and Cordova SQLite. The application is inserting data into sqlite if data is not exists in sqlite but if data exists in sqlite. Then, application is replacing the old data. The following is my code. But I can't insert data into sqlite database.

Create Database

```
db = window.openDatabase("chatChannel.db", "1", "Demo SQLite Test", "2000");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_channel(id interger primary key, channel_name text unique, last_text text)")
```

Insert Data

```
  var query = "INSERT INTO chat_channel (channel_name, last_text) VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (last_text) VALUES (?)";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [channel, $scope.messageContent], [$scope.messageContent]);
```

May I know how to insert data into cordova sqlite if record not exist in sqlite database and update data if data is exists in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REPLACE (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

```
REPLACE INTO chat_channel (channel_name, last_text) VALUES(?,?)
```

However for it to work correctly you need to have a unique or primary key involved in the request (in your case that would work if channel_name is the primary key of chat_channel, or if it is unique), see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html for details on the conflict resolution of REPLACE

Comment: It not work. What I want to do is when channel_name available in sqlite database, then it will replace the last_text in database but if channel_name is not in database, it will insert a new data into database.